# Use MongoDB $sort twice

Tags: mongodb

Is there a way to use the $sort operator twice within a single aggregation pipeline?
I know that using a singular $sort with two keys works properly, i.e. sort by the first key, then the second.

My current project requires multiple $sort stages to exist, for example

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $sort: {
      "age": 1
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      "score": -1
    }
  }
])
```

Currently, the second stage doesn't respect the result of the first stage. Is there any workaround for that?

Is it possible to, for example, assign each document a new field 'index' after the first stage, storing its index within the current array of results, and use that field in the second $sort stage?

Comment: Possible, but why? What's wrong with `$sort: {age:1,score:-1}` ?

Comment: Users will be able to freely combine stages, i.e. they toggle a button, and the referenced stage is added to an aggregation pipeline. So it is not possible to know inbefore which and how many $sort stages I'll have to deal with, so I'd ideally want them to work independently.

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple value in '$sort'.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$sort": {
      "age": 1,
      "score": -1
    }
  }
])
```

I have define mongo playground link, you can refer it

https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZaRX_XNSXhu

Comment: I know this is an option, but as I stated above, my project requires the use of multiple $sort stages. Combining them into one would be ideal, but I can't assure that this will always be the possible, hence my search for a workaround.